# How to configure OpenTelemetry agent for an Akka application

Tags: akka, open-telemetry, observability

I am trying to export metrics and traces from my Akka app written in Scala using OpenTelemetry agent with the purpose of consuming the data in [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org/docs/monitoring-plugins/trace/get-started/).

Technology stack for my application:

- Akka - 2.6.*
- RabbitMQ (amqp client 5.12.*)
- PostgreSQL (jdbc 42.2.*)

I've added OpenTelemetry instrumentation runtime dependency to `build.sbt`:

```scala
  val runtimeDependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq(
    "io.opentelemetry.instrumentation" % "opentelemetry-instrumentation-api" % otelInstrumentationVersion % "runtime"
  )
...
  libraryDependencies ++= compileDependencies ++ testDependencies ++ runtimeDependencies,
```

I am passing OpenTelemetry configurations in a properties file:

```sh
export JAVA_OPTS="... \
-javaagent:lib/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-javaagent-all-v1.6.0.jar \
-Dotel.javaagent.configuration-file=lib/opentelemetry/otel.properties"
```

The only other related piece in my code is the properties file:

```java
otel.service.name=my-app
otel.traces.exporter=jaeger
otel.propagators=jaeger
```

I do receive some traces in OpenSearch, but they are disparate and unrelated whereas I would expect them to be linked. For example a message is received on RabbitMQ topic, it makes it's way into an actor, the latter eventually issues a SQL query. As a result I could see for each execution how much time did each step take.

This is an approximate view that I get in OpenSearch: [image]

I would love to be able to follow documentation, but I find that OpenTelemetry's [configuration guide](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/agent-config.md) is scarce at this point.

**Update**:

Not sure whether this is relevant, but I get a warning on datapreper:

```sh
2021-09-29T16:50:50,861 [raw-pipeline-prepper-worker-5-thread-1] WARN  com.amazon.dataprepper.plugins.prepper.oteltrace.OTelTraceRawPrepper - Missing trace group for SpanId: 922097e31cf96c72
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I got around by running across [this issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/issues/173) and then reading about how to [surpress specific instrumentations](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/suppressing-instrumentation.md#suppressing-specific-agent-instrumentation).

So to reduce clutter in tracing dashboard, one would add something as following to the properties file (or equivalent via environment variables):

```java
otel.instrumentation.rabbitmq.enabled=false
otel.instrumentation.grpc.enabled=false
```

Note that I removed the two cluttering instrumentation libraries peculiar for my use case. For another application one wold choose other libraries from link # 2 above. In this way the spans that you as application developer declare will become roots.